# Start multiple node microservices with single command in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file

#### Start multiple node servers with single command on windows operating system with help of batch file (.bat)

let's assume this is my folder structure with all microservices and all `package.json` have `start`, `dev` and `test` scripts defined.

```
project-root
|
+--auth-service
|   |
|   +--package.json
|
+--user-service
|   |
|   +--package.json
|
+--product-service
|   |
|   +--package.json
|
+--order-service
    |
    +--package.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Save this file as run.bat on project-root directory

```
set type=%1

IF "%type%" EQU "install" (
    set command=npm install
) ELSE (
    set command=npm run %type%
)

IF "%type%" EQU "" (
    set command=npm run dev
)

start cmd /k "cd auth-service && %command% && exit"
start cmd /k "cd user-service && %command% && exit"
start cmd /k "cd product-service && %command% && exit"
start cmd /k "cd order-service && %command% && exit"
```

> As you can see if no parameter passed services will run on `dev` mode.

#### From project-root directory open cmd and run command

To install all packages

```
run.bat install
```

To run in dev mode ( depends on `dev` script on respective `package.json` )

```
run.bat dev
```

To run in start mode ( depends on `start` script on respective `package.json` )

```
run.bat start
```

To run test mode ( depends on `test` script on respective `package.json` )

```
run.bat test
```

this will start a new cmd on respective directories and start executing given command... It is pretty handy when you need to start all services at once.

#### Note: Use this only for development stage.

Comment: `start /d "auth-service" %command%` should do.